# Google Maps Android API 地図ズームレベル17f以上で連続スクロールするとクラッシュする

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps

Google Maps Android API （V2) を使用してアプリを開発しております。
先週末からズームレベル17f以上の地図縮尺（建物外郭や、インドア表示される詳細地図表示縮尺）で地図を連続スクロールすると、アプリがクラッシュする現象に遭遇しております。
また以前に比べ、上記縮尺での表示がかなり遅くなっているように感じております。
※ 今月中旬までは当現象は発生しておりませんでした。

原因、回避方法についてお知恵をいただけませんでしょうか？

【端末】
HTC J One （HTL22） Android 4.4.2
Nexus 5X  Android 6.0
Sony Xperia （SO-03H)  Android 6.0
※ 上記端末の「Google Play 開発者サービス」は全て「バージョン 9.6.83(038-133155058)」です

【開発環境】
Android Studio 1.4
※ 使用しているplay-service-mapsは9.6.1

【再現手順】
(1) 地図の縮尺を詳細表示（zoom Level = 17.0f付近）にする
(2) 1秒間に1回程度の間隔で、小刻みに地図をスクロールする（1cm～2cmくらいフリック操作）
(3) 5秒に1回程度、地図の描画が完了するまで操作を休止する

だいたい一分程度で再現します
※ 地図の地域により再現率は異なりますが、「東京都文京区の千駄木駅付近」だと発生しやすいです。
※ また、(3)の手順で、地図描画が完全に完了する直前にスクロールすると発生しやすいです。

【備考】
ちなみに同様の操作を海外（ニューヨーク、上海）で行いましたが、再現できませんでした。
ログを見るとANR、OpenGLのエラーがありますので、詳細縮尺地図の描画遅延が問題ではないかと疑っております。
（今月中旬にリリースされた「Google Play 開発者サービス」が関係している？）

以下に現象発生時のDDMS エラー出力ログを添付します。
※ なお、Adjust のAbort messageが出力されていますが、本件とは無関係のようです。
see) https://github.com/adjust/android_sdk/pull/212/commits/ae3873679b7cd5c08535c0d9fe9d5a3f478b5cb8

----<以下、DDMSログ>----------------------------------------------------------

```
09-29 17:56:35.424: A/libc(20596): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 20652 (GLThread 255)
09-29 17:56:35.527: A/DEBUG(15128): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
09-29 17:56:35.527: A/DEBUG(15128): Build fingerprint: 'google/bullhead/bullhead:6.0/MDB08L/2343525:user/release-keys'
09-29 17:56:35.527: A/DEBUG(15128): Revision: 'rev_1.0'
09-29 17:56:35.528: A/DEBUG(15128): ABI: 'arm'
09-29 17:56:35.528: A/DEBUG(15128): pid: 20596, tid: 20652, name: GLThread 255  >>> jp.co.xxxx.myApp <<<
09-29 17:56:35.528: A/DEBUG(15128): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0
09-29 17:56:36.264: A/DEBUG(15128): Abort message: 'PRODUCTION: Adjust is running in Production mode. Use this setting only for the build that you want to publish. Set the environment to `sandbox` if you want to test your app!'
09-29 17:56:36.264: A/DEBUG(15128):     r0 bebd35b0  r1 00000000  r2 00000018  r3 00000000
09-29 17:56:36.264: A/DEBUG(15128):     r4 00000018  r5 00000000  r6 00000001  r7 d752e320
09-29 17:56:36.264: A/DEBUG(15128):     r8 00000000  r9 d46eec80  sl 00000002  fp d4694750
09-29 17:56:36.265: A/DEBUG(15128):     ip ea001da8  sp d69f2148  lr e9c8af15  pc f6ed46a4  cpsr 00030010
09-29 17:56:36.280: A/DEBUG(15128): backtrace:
09-29 17:56:36.281: A/DEBUG(15128):     #00 pc 000176a4  /system/lib/libc.so (__memcpy_base+148)
09-29 17:56:36.281: A/DEBUG(15128):     #01 pc 00125f11  /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (EsxVertexArrayObject::UpdateInternalVbos(EsxDrawDescriptor const*, unsigned int, EsxAttributeDesc const*)+1116)
09-29 17:56:36.282: A/DEBUG(15128):     #02 pc 00157af5  /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (A4xVertexArrayObject::CalcVfdRegs(EsxDrawDescriptor const*, A4xVfdRegs*, int)+856)
09-29 17:56:36.282: A/DEBUG(15128):     #03 pc 0015ce0f  /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (A4xContext::ValidateVfdState(EsxDrawDescriptor const*, int)+38)
09-29 17:56:36.282: A/DEBUG(15128):     #04 pc 001668ff  /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (A4xContext::ValidateState(EsxDrawDescriptor const*)+1126)
09-29 17:56:36.282: A/DEBUG(15128):     #05 pc 00166e7d  /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (A4xContext::HwValidateGfxState(EsxDrawDescriptor const*)+4)
09-29 17:56:36.282: A/DEBUG(15128):     #06 pc 000e6f0b  /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (EsxContext::ValidateGfxState(EsxDrawDescriptor const*)+442)
09-29 17:56:36.282: A/DEBUG(15128):     #07 pc 000dc509  /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (EsxContext::DrawArraysInstanced(EsxPrimType, int, unsigned int, unsigned int)+112)
09-29 17:56:36.283: A/DEBUG(15128):     #08 pc 000c8fff  /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (EsxContext::GlDrawArrays(unsigned int, int, int)+62)
09-29 17:56:36.283: A/DEBUG(15128):     #09 pc 000124a5  /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno.so (glDrawArrays+84)
09-29 17:56:36.283: A/DEBUG(15128):     #10 pc 7466afb5  /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot.oat (offset 0x1ec4000)
09-29 17:56:38.282: E/NativeCrashListener(877): Exception dealing with report
09-29 17:56:38.282: E/NativeCrashListener(877): android.system.ErrnoException: read failed: EAGAIN (Try again)
09-29 17:56:38.282: E/NativeCrashListener(877):     at libcore.io.Posix.readBytes(Native Method)
09-29 17:56:38.282: E/NativeCrashListener(877):     at libcore.io.Posix.read(Posix.java:169)
09-29 17:56:38.282: E/NativeCrashListener(877):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.read(BlockGuardOs.java:230)
09-29 17:56:38.282: E/NativeCrashListener(877):     at android.system.Os.read(Os.java:367)
09-29 17:56:38.282: E/NativeCrashListener(877):     at com.android.server.am.NativeCrashListener.consumeNativeCrashData(NativeCrashListener.java:240)
09-29 17:56:38.282: E/NativeCrashListener(877):     at com.android.server.am.NativeCrashListener.run(NativeCrashListener.java:138)
09-29 17:56:42.777: E/clatd(4218): plat_prefix/dns(ipv4only.arpa) status = 7/No address associated with hostname
09-29 17:56:43.877: E/WifiHAL(877): Error polling socket
09-29 17:57:02.438: A/DEBUG(15128): Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_06
09-29 17:57:02.438: E/DEBUG(15128): AM write failed: Broken pipe
09-29 17:57:02.813: E/Cataloger(4280): syncFile:/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/jp.co.xxxx.myApp/cache/cache_bd.0
09-29 17:57:02.815: E/Cataloger(4280): need not sync path:/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/jp.co.xxxx.myApp/cache/cache_bd.0
09-29 17:57:02.815: E/Cataloger(4280): syncFile:/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/jp.co.xxxx.myApp/cache/cache_vts_inaka_jp.co.xxxx.myApp.0
09-29 17:57:02.815: E/Cataloger(4280): need not sync path:/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/jp.co.xxxx.myApp/cache/cache_vts_inaka_jp.co.xxxx.myApp.0
09-29 17:57:02.815: E/Cataloger(4280): syncFile:/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/jp.co.xxxx.myApp/cache/cache_vts_jp.co.xxxx.myApp.0
09-29 17:57:02.816: E/Cataloger(4280): need not sync path:/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/jp.co.xxxx.myApp/cache/cache_vts_jp.co.xxxx.myApp.0
09-29 17:57:02.816: E/Cataloger(4280): syncFile:/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/jp.co.xxxx.myApp/cache/cache_r.0
09-29 17:57:02.816: E/Cataloger(4280): need not sync path:/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/jp.co.xxxx.myApp/cache/cache_r.0
09-29 17:57:02.816: E/Cataloger(4280): syncFile:/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/jp.co.xxxx.myApp/cache/cache_r.m
09-29 17:57:02.818: E/Cataloger(4280): need not sync path:/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/jp.co.xxxx.myApp/cache/cache_r.m
09-29 17:57:02.831: E/Cataloger(4280): syncFile:/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/jp.co.xxxx.myApp/cache/cache_vts_no_pois_jp.co.xxxx.myApp.m
09-29 17:57:02.834: E/Cataloger(4280): need not sync path:/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/jp.co.xxxx.myApp/cache/cache_vts_no_pois_jp.co.xxxx.myApp.m
09-29 17:57:02.834: E/Cataloger(4280): syncFile:/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/jp.co.xxxx.myApp/cache/cache_vts_jp.co.xxxx.myApp.m
09-29 17:57:02.835: E/Cataloger(4280): need not sync path:/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/jp.co.xxxx.myApp/cache/cache_vts_jp.co.xxxx.myApp.m
09-29 17:57:02.836: E/Cataloger(4280): syncFile:/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/jp.co.xxxx.myApp/cache/cache_its.m
09-29 17:57:02.837: E/Cataloger(4280): need not sync path:/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/jp.co.xxxx.myApp/cache/cache_its.m
09-29 17:57:02.850: E/Cataloger(4280): syncFile:/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/jp.co.xxxx.myApp/cache/cache_its_ter.m
09-29 17:57:02.850: E/Cataloger(4280): need not sync path:/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/jp.co.xxxx.myApp/cache/cache_its_ter.m
09-29 17:57:02.850: E/Cataloger(4280): syncFile:/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/jp.co.xxxx.myApp/cache/cache_bd.m
09-29 17:57:02.850: E/Cataloger(4280): need not sync path:/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/jp.co.xxxx.myApp/cache/cache_bd.m
09-29 17:57:02.850: E/Cataloger(4280): syncFile:/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/jp.co.xxxx.myApp/cache/cache_vts_labl_jp.co.xxxx.myApp.m
09-29 17:57:02.850: E/Cataloger(4280): need not sync path:/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/jp.co.xxxx.myApp/cache/cache_vts_labl_jp.co.xxxx.myApp.m
09-29 17:57:02.850: E/Cataloger(4280): syncFile:/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/jp.co.xxxx.myApp/cache/cache_vts_inaka_jp.co.xxxx.myApp.m
09-29 17:57:02.850: E/Cataloger(4280): need not sync path:/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/jp.co.xxxx.myApp/cache/cache_vts_inaka_jp.co.xxxx.myApp.m
09-29 17:57:04.598: E/ActivityManager(877): ANR in jp.co.xxxx.myApp (jp.co.xxxx.myApp/.application.MainActivity)
09-29 17:57:04.598: E/ActivityManager(877): PID: 20596
09-29 17:57:04.598: E/ActivityManager(877): Reason: Input dispatching timed out (Waiting to send non-key event because the touched window has not finished processing certain input events that were delivered to it over 500.0ms ago.  Wait queue length: 18.  Wait queue head age: 5925.2ms.)
09-29 17:57:04.598: E/ActivityManager(877): Load: 8.38 / 8.12 / 8.4
09-29 17:57:04.598: E/ActivityManager(877): CPU usage from 0ms to 22572ms later:
09-29 17:57:04.598: E/ActivityManager(877):   90% 15128/debuggerd: 85% user + 4.5% kernel / faults: 6049 minor
09-29 17:57:04.598: E/ActivityManager(877):   14% 877/system_server: 3.7% user + 11% kernel / faults: 7506 minor 1 major
09-29 17:57:04.598: E/ActivityManager(877):   3% 2867/com.android.systemui: 1.2% user + 1.8% kernel / faults: 3181 minor
09-29 17:57:04.598: E/ActivityManager(877):   1.8% 3348/com.android.phone: 0.8% user + 1% kernel / faults: 2121 minor
09-29 17:57:04.598: E/ActivityManager(877):   0% 487/debuggerd64: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 3709 minor
09-29 17:57:04.598: E/ActivityManager(877):   0% 3289/com.android.nfc: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 900 minor
09-29 17:57:04.598: E/ActivityManager(877):   0.5% 368/surfaceflinger: 0.2% user + 0.3% kernel / faults: 7 minor
09-29 17:57:04.598: E/ActivityManager(877):   0.5% 3268/com.quicinc.cne.CNEService: 0.2% user + 0.3% kernel / faults: 944 minor
09-29 17:57:04.598: E/ActivityManager(877):   0.4% 19586/kworker/u12:5: 0% user + 0.4% kernel
09-29 17:57:04.598: E/ActivityManager(877):   0.3% 8/rcu_preempt: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
09-29 17:57:04.598: E/ActivityManager(877):   0.3% 285/msm-core:sampli: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
09-29 17:57:04.598: E/ActivityManager(877):   0% 3325/com.qualcomm.qti.rcsimsbootstraputil: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 659 minor
09-29 17:57:04.598: E/ActivityManager(877):   0.3% 2814/VosMCThread: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
09-29 17:57:04.598: E/ActivityManager(877):   0.3% 14096/com.android.vending: 0.3% user + 0% kernel / faults: 64 minor
09-29 17:57:04.598: E/ActivityManager(877):   0% 3307/com.qualcomm.qti.rcsbootstraputil: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 587 minor
09-29 17:57:04.598: E/ActivityManager(877):   0.1% 275/mmcqd/0: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
09-29 17:57:04.598: E/ActivityManager(877):   0.1% 15034/kworker/2:1: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
09-29 17:57:04.598: E/ActivityManager(877):   0.1% 3/ksoftirqd/0: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
09-29 17:57:04.598: E/ActivityManager(877):   0.1% 8959/kworker/u12:6: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
09-29 17:57:04.598: E/ActivityManager(877):   0.1% 8960/mdss_fb0: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
09-29 17:57:04.598: E/ActivityManager(877):   0.1% 16348/adbd: 0% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 37 minor
09-29 17:57:04.598: E/ActivityManager(877):   0% 12/ksoftirqd/1: 0% user + 0% kernel
09-29 17:57:04.598: E/ActivityManager(877):   0% 59/system: 0% user + 0% kernel
09-29 17:57:04.598: E/ActivityManager(877):   0% 129/kswapd0: 0% user + 0% kernel
09-29 17:57:04.598: E/ActivityManager(877):   0% 253/cfinteractive: 0% user + 0% kernel
09-29 17:57:04.598: E/ActivityManager(877):   0% 335/logd: 0% user + 0% kernel
09-29 17:57:04.598: E/ActivityManager(877):   0% 499/thermal-engine: 0% user + 0% kernel
09-29 17:57:04.598: E/ActivityManager(877):   0% 14996/.esfm: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 297 minor 1 major
09-29 17:57:04.598: E/ActivityManager(877):   0% 19362/kworker/0:0: 0% user + 0% kernel
09-29 17:57:04.598: E/ActivityManager(877):   0% 19531/kworker/u12:1: 0% user + 0% kernel
09-29 17:57:04.598: E/ActivityManager(877):   0% 20532/kworker/3:3: 0% user + 0% kernel
09-29 17:57:04.598: E/ActivityManager(877):   0% 16/ksoftirqd/2: 0% user + 0% kernel
09-29 17:57:04.598: E/ActivityManager(877):   0% 20/ksoftirqd/3: 0% user + 0% kernel
09-29 17:57:04.598: E/ActivityManager(877):   0% 46/kworker/u13:0: 0% user + 0% kernel
09-29 17:57:04.598: E/ActivityManager(877):   0% 192/spi7: 0% user + 0% kernel
09-29 17:57:04.598: E/ActivityManager(877):   0% 372/msm_irqbalance: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1 minor
09-29 17:57:04.598: E/ActivityManager(877):   0% 406/irq/215-fc38800: 0% user + 0% kernel
09-29 17:57:04.598: E/ActivityManager(877):   0% 495/qmuxd: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 13 minor
09-29 17:57:04.598: E/ActivityManager(877):   0% 496/perfd: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 32 minor
09-29 17:57:04.598: E/ActivityManager(877):   0% 3862/com.google.android.gms: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 2 minor
09-29 17:57:04.598: E/ActivityManager(877):   0% 4280/com.estrongs.android.pop: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 273 minor
09-29 17:57:04.598: E/ActivityManager(877):   0% 7795/kworker/1:1: 0% user + 0% kernel
09-29 17:57:04.598: E/ActivityManager(877):   0% 19585/kworker/u12:2: 0% user + 0% kernel
09-29 17:57:04.598: E/ActivityManager(877):   0% 19719/kworker/u12:8: 0% user + 0% kernel
09-29 17:57:04.598: E/ActivityManager(877):  +0% 21035/kworker/u12:3: 0% user + 0% kernel
09-29 17:57:04.598: E/ActivityManager(877): 30% TOTAL: 23% user + 5.8% kernel + 0.3% iowait + 0.2% irq + 0% softirq
09-29 17:57:04.598: E/ActivityManager(877): CPU usage from 21993ms to 22522ms later with 99% awake:
09-29 17:57:04.598: E/ActivityManager(877):   9.1% 877/system_server: 5.4% user + 3.6% kernel
09-29 17:57:04.598: E/ActivityManager(877):     7.3% 890/ActivityManager: 5.4% user + 1.8% kernel
09-29 17:57:04.598: E/ActivityManager(877):   1.4% 253/cfinteractive: 0% user + 1.4% kernel
09-29 17:57:04.598: E/ActivityManager(877): 1.9% TOTAL: 0.4% user + 1.4% kernel
09-29 17:57:06.746: E/WifiHAL(877): Error polling socket
09-29 17:57:12.011: E/ActivityManager(877): ANR in jp.co.xxxx.myApp (jp.co.xxxx.myApp/.application.MainActivity)
09-29 17:57:12.011: E/ActivityManager(877): PID: 0
09-29 17:57:12.011: E/ActivityManager(877): Reason: Input dispatching timed out (Waiting to send non-key event because the touched window has not finished processing certain input events that were delivered to it over 500.0ms ago.  Wait queue length: 18.  Wait queue head age: 10945.6ms.)
09-29 17:57:12.011: E/ActivityManager(877): Load: 8.24 / 8.1 / 8.39
09-29 17:57:12.011: E/ActivityManager(877): CPU usage from 39ms to -7375ms ago:
09-29 17:57:12.011: E/ActivityManager(877):   53% 877/system_server: 13% user + 40% kernel / faults: 8882 minor
09-29 17:57:12.011: E/ActivityManager(877):   8.9% 2867/com.android.systemui: 2.8% user + 6% kernel / faults: 3074 minor
09-29 17:57:12.011: E/ActivityManager(877):   6.8% 15128/debuggerd: 1.6% user + 5.2% kernel / faults: 4424 minor
09-29 17:57:12.011: E/ActivityManager(877):   5.6% 3348/com.android.phone: 2.4% user + 3.2% kernel / faults: 2427 minor
09-29 17:57:12.011: E/ActivityManager(877):   2.8% 487/debuggerd64: 0.9% user + 1.8% kernel / faults: 3708 minor
09-29 17:57:12.011: E/ActivityManager(877):   2% 3289/com.android.nfc: 1% user + 0.9% kernel / faults: 899 minor
09-29 17:57:12.011: E/ActivityManager(877):   0.4% 2995/com.google.android.gms.persistent: 0.2% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 489 minor
09-29 17:57:12.011: E/ActivityManager(877):   1.6% 3268/com.quicinc.cne.CNEService: 0.9% user + 0.6% kernel / faults: 943 minor
09-29 17:57:12.011: E/ActivityManager(877):   0.9% 3325/com.qualcomm.qti.rcsimsbootstraputil: 0.5% user + 0.4% kernel / faults: 663 minor
09-29 17:57:12.011: E/ActivityManager(877):   0.8% 253/cfinteractive: 0% user + 0.8% kernel
09-29 17:57:12.011: E/ActivityManager(877):   0.8% 3307/com.qualcomm.qti.rcsbootstraputil: 0.6% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 585 minor
09-29 17:57:12.011: E/ActivityManager(877):   0.6% 3862/com.google.android.gms: 0.4% user + 0.2% kernel / faults: 371 minor
09-29 17:57:12.011: E/ActivityManager(877):   0.4% 8/rcu_preempt: 0% user + 0.4% kernel
09-29 17:57:12.011: E/ActivityManager(877):   0.4% 275/mmcqd/0: 0% user + 0.4% kernel
09-29 17:57:12.011: E/ActivityManager(877):   0.4% 285/msm-core:sampli: 0% user + 0.4% kernel
09-29 17:57:12.011: E/ActivityManager(877):   0.1% 3113/com.google.process.gapps: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 213 minor
09-29 17:57:12.011: E/ActivityManager(877):   0.4% 19585/kworker/u12:2: 0% user + 0.4% kernel
09-29 17:57:12.011: E/ActivityManager(877):   0.2% 3/ksoftirqd/0: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
09-29 17:57:12.011: E/ActivityManager(877):   0.2% 12/ksoftirqd/1: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
09-29 17:57:12.011: E/ActivityManager(877):   0.2% 406/irq/215-fc38800: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
09-29 17:57:12.011: E/ActivityManager(877):   0.2% 2814/VosMCThread: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
09-29 17:57:12.011: E/ActivityManager(877):   0% 14211/kworker/0:1: 0% user + 0% kernel
09-29 17:57:12.011: E/ActivityManager(877):   0.1% 16/ksoftirqd/2: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
09-29 17:57:12.011: E/ActivityManager(877):   0.1% 20/ksoftirqd/3: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
09-29 17:57:12.011: E/ActivityManager(877):   0.1% 46/kworker/u13:0: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
09-29 17:57:12.011: E/ActivityManager(877):   0.1% 335/logd: 0% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 3 minor
09-29 17:57:12.011: E/ActivityManager(877):   0% 365/healthd: 0% user + 0% kernel
09-29 17:57:12.011: E/ActivityManager(877):   0% 366/lmkd: 0% user + 0% kernel
09-29 17:57:12.011: E/ActivityManager(877):   0% 367/servicemanager: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1 minor
09-29 17:57:12.011: E/ActivityManager(877):   0.1% 368/surfaceflinger: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
09-29 17:57:12.011: E/ActivityManager(877):   0.1% 372/msm_irqbalance: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
09-29 17:57:12.011: E/ActivityManager(877):   0% 463/dmcrypt_write: 0% user + 0% kernel
09-29 17:57:12.011: E/ActivityManager(877):   0% 475/jbd2/dm-2-8: 0% user + 0% kernel
09-29 17:57:12.011: E/ActivityManager(877):   0.1% 499/thermal-engine: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
09-29 17:57:12.011: E/ActivityManager(877):   0% 575/cnss-daemon: 0% user + 0% kernel
09-29 17:57:12.011: E/ActivityManager(877):   0% 2824/wlan_logging_th: 0% user + 0% kernel
09-29 17:57:12.011: E/ActivityManager(877):   0.1% 8959/kworker/u12:6: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
09-29 17:57:12.011: E/ActivityManager(877):   0.1% 14096/com.android.vending: 0.1% user + 0% kernel / faults: 2 minor
09-29 17:57:12.011: E/ActivityManager(877):   0.1% 15034/kworker/2:1: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
09-29 17:57:12.011: E/ActivityManager(877):   0.1% 16348/adbd: 0.1% user + 0% kernel / faults: 15 minor
09-29 17:57:12.011: E/ActivityManager(877):   0.1% 19586/kworker/u12:5: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
09-29 17:57:12.011: E/ActivityManager(877):   0% 20276/logcat: 0% user + 0% kernel
09-29 17:57:12.011: E/ActivityManager(877): 23% TOTAL: 6.9% user + 15% kernel + 0.3% iowait + 0.2% irq + 0.1% softirq
09-29 17:57:12.011: E/ActivityManager(877): CPU usage from 6803ms to 7327ms later:
09-29 17:57:12.011: E/ActivityManager(877):   7.3% 877/system_server: 1.8% user + 5.5% kernel
09-29 17:57:12.011: E/ActivityManager(877):     7.3% 890/ActivityManager: 1.8% user + 5.5% kernel
09-29 17:57:12.011: E/ActivityManager(877): 1.9% TOTAL: 0% user + 1.9% kernel
09-29 17:57:14.498: E/QCALOG(605): [MessageQ] ProcessNewMessage: [LOWI-SERVER] unknown deliver target [OS-Agent]
```

----<以上、DDMSログ>----------------------------------------------------------

Comment: 自分のアプリ(未リリース)でも発生してます。V2マップで東京から初めて西に中国あたりまで行くと落ちますね。気が付いたのは今年初頭。環境はAndroid ver4.2.2、関係ないと思いますが機種はAQUOS ZETA SH-06E(古!)です。
V1マップのバージョンは落ちません(vv;)。

Comment: 貴重な情報、ありがとうございます。
今年初頭から発生していたのですね。

当方のアプリではカーナビのように位置情報更新（毎秒）で現在地を地図中心に更新しております。
本年9月第2週に新機能の確認のため長時間テストしましたが、本現象は発生しておりませんでした。

ただ、発生しやすい場所があるようなので気が付かなかったのかもしれません。
また、端末（OS？）によっても発生しやすいものと発生しにくいものがあるようです。
HTC J One HTL22(Android 4.4.2) は発生しにくいですが、Nexus 5X(Android 6.0)ではかなりすぐに発生します。

なお、V2 APIを使用していると思われるGooglePlayに公開されている他のアプリでも、本現象が発生することを確認しました。

Comment: 再現手順について追記です。
地図を詳細縮尺（ズームレベル17f以上）にした後、地図仰角（TILT）を若干傾けた状態にしてから地図スクロールすると、すぐに再現することを確認しました。
※東京都心部表示中ならばほぼ５回程度のスクロールで再現します。

以上、ご参考まで。

Comment: gmaps-api-issues に不具合報告しました。（10/7現在、status：Acceptedになりました）
https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=10615&q=zoom%20level%2017&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal